# Make rounded LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, shapes

i'm creating a listview array from of LinearLayout programmatically and i want to make rounded corners so i created a drawable resource like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="40dp"
        />

    <padding
        android:top="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"/>
</shape>
```

The code of the LinearLayout is this

```
LinearLayout linearLayout= new LinearLayout(getContext());
            linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layout= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                200,
                100
        );


        layout.setMargins(20,20,20,20);

        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(layout);
        linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded);
        linearLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Log.i("Test selected","");
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

                return false;
            }
        });
```

The problem is that the shape of the elements is not rounded. Where is my mistake?? Thanks to every one sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

To make the layout having round corner:

1. **You have to define a xml file having properties of round corner having name rounded.xml in res/drawable** (You can save any name)

   shape 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shape="rectangle">

   ```
   <gradient
       android:endColor="#000000"
       android:startColor="#000000"/>

   <corners
       android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
       android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
       android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
       android:topRightRadius="7dp"/>
   ```
2. Define your activity as:

   ```
   LinearLayout linearLayout;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       linearLayout= new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
       linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

   //Use framelayout.layoutparams not linearlayout.layoutparams
       FrameLayout.LayoutParams layout= new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(200,100);   

   //Use setContentView to show this layout in your activity
       setContentView(linearLayout,layout);

       layout.setMargins(50,50,50,50);

       linearLayout.setLayoutParams(layout);
       linearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
       linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded);
       linearLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

       @Override
       public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
           Log.i("Test selected","");
           v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

           return false;
       }
   });
   ```

I have checked with:

```
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layout= new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

And the color of layout is set to black in rounded.xml

And the output is:

[image: Output]